# Daily backups of AWS RDS PostgreSQL which save to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

So I'm having issues with configuring daily backups on AWS RDS PostgreSQL database which should then save on AWS S3 Bucket.

I have my database and S3 bucket up and running, I've figured out there are snapshots but apparently you can't really do anything with them, since they're on AWS RDS and that's it.

I'm quite a beginner at this and I've been googling like crazy for the past couple of hours and still have not found the solution. The closest I was, was with this - [Exporting a AWS Postgres RDS Table to AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899210/exporting-a-aws-postgres-rds-table-to-aws-s3) but I still don't know how to do the whole table.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: *"I've figured out there are snapshots but apparently you can't really do anything with them, since they're on AWS RDS and that's it."*  You can use them to create a new RDS instance with identical data, and you can do this much more quickly than you would ever be able to restore a conventional backup.  What did you intend to do with them?